# Initiating directive from controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-controller

I'm having trouble figuring out a way to initiate a directive once the data has been returned. I'm trying to build a report using html tables and ng-repeat. The report object is generated using a Factory. The factory method returns the report object and ng-repeat builds the table. I found a DataTable's directive which takes the html and applies the JQuery plugin.

**Problem:** If the datatables directive is called before the table is created, it fails. I need to control when the directive calls the function `element.getTable(options)`.

I've found another directive which is able to determine when ng-repeat is done using the `$last` but is there a way to use that ngRepeat directive to initate the dataTables directive from the controller?

HTML:

```
<!-- partials/reports/limbo.html -->
<div ng-visible="$root.ReportReady">
    <table data-name="CheckedOutFiles_Report" class="report" my-table>
        <thead>
            <tr class="reportHeader" >
                <th>Filename</th>
                <th>File Url</th>
                <th>Checked Out To</th>
                <th>Modified</th>

            </tr>           
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <!-- new row for every file -->
            <tr ng-repeat="file in ReportModel.report" on-finish-render>
                <td>{{file.fileName}}</td>
                <td>{{file.fileUrl}}</td>
                <td>{{file.checkedTo}}</td>
                <td>{{file.modified}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>    
</div>
```

Report Controller:

```
spApp.controller('limboReportCtrl', 
    function limboReportCtrl($scope,$q,UserService,GroupService, SiteService, ReportService){

        $scope.ReportModel = {};

        $scope.createReport = function (){
            ReportService.CheckedOutFiles().then(function (data){
                console.log(data);
                $scope.ReportModel.report = data;
            })
        }
        $scope.createReport();

        $scope.$on('ngRepeatFinished', function(ngRepeatFinishedEvent) {
            //you also get the actual event object
            //do stuff, execute functions -- whatever...
            console.log('somethingsomething');
        });
    }
);
```

Directive to handle callback function when ng-repeat is done:

```
spApp.directive('onFinishRender', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            if (scope.$last === true) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    scope.$emit('ngRepeatFinished');
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

DataTables directive:

```
spApp.directive('myTable', function ($rootScope, $timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E, A, C',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            var reportName = $(this).data('name');
            //DATA TABLE OPTIONS 


            //THIS WORKS BUT RELIES ON A SET TIME TO CALL DATATABLES AND ISN'T DEPENDENT ON WHEN THE TABLE IS READY. IF CALLED BEFORE TABLE GENERATED, IT WILL NOT WORK
            var timer = $timeout(function (){
                console.log('calling dataTables');
                var dTable = element.dataTable(scope.options);
                new $.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns( dTable );
                $rootScope.ReportReady = true;
            },3000);

            //BEFORE THE CODE BELOW, $TIMEOUT DESTROYED PERFORMANCE OF THE ENTIRE APPLICATION. FOLLOWING THIS BLOG POST, PERFORMANCE SIGNIFICANTLY IMPROVED http://tinyurl.com/naouvv7
            timer.then(
                function (){
                    console.log("Timer resolved ", Date.now());
            },
                function (){
                    console.log("Timer rejected ", Date.now());
                }
            );

            scope.$on('$destroy',
                function(e){
                    $timeout.cancel(timer);
                }
            )
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you are using the DataTable directive and also what purpose your "myTable" directive is serving? Do you just want to display the data returned from your factory?

Comment: I like the functionality of this plugin and this directive allows me to enhance the functionality of my html reports.

Comment: Have you checked out ng-grid?

Comment: I have, I prefer the functionality of DataTables however.

Comment: So which dataTable directive are you using? I see that you are using the jQuery version of dataTable.

Comment: Yea I'm using the jQuery DataTables. Someone turned it into a jQuery library. It works well with my application, I just need to better control when it triggers. I'm currently trying to use $watch and $rootScope property to trigger it. I'll update if that works.

Comment: If you own "Mastering Web Application Development with AngularJS" there is a neat little section on how to wrap jQuery plugins inside Angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by changing the directive for dataTables:

```
        scope.$watch(
            function() {return $rootScope.ReportReady}, 
            function (newValue, oldValue){
            if(newValue){
                console.log('calling dataTables');
                var dTable = element.dataTable(scope.options);
                new $.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns( dTable );
                $rootScope.ReportVisible = true;
            }
        })
```

In the controller:

```
    $scope.$on('ngRepeatFinished', function(ngRepeatFinishedEvent) {
        //set a variable to true which datatables directive is watching
        //when that variable is true, initiate datatables
        $rootScope.ReportReady = true;
    });
```

So when the page renders and ng-repeat is done, it changes the rootScope property. the directive is watching that property and sees that it's changed so calls the function to create the table. So now I have full control of when that last step is initiated without using $timeout.